# MessageBox.Show sporadically don't show on catching exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a Visual Studio extension in C# and I get a strange behavior on managing exception and displaying error messages. Basically, I just want to add some details to the exception message to help me investigate in case of a problem.

It all starts from a command on a context menu item and I suspect it may be related to threads management behind the async/await mechanism. But I am not sure I guess correctly and I am not able to find any solution. HELP!

It starts from my menu item callback:

```
internal sealed class My_RunAnalysis
{
    //...
    public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
    {
        // Switch to the main thread - the call to AddCommand in PS_RunAnalysis's constructor requires
        // the UI thread.
        await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

        OleMenuCommandService commandService = await package.GetServiceAsync((typeof(IMenuCommandService))) as OleMenuCommandService;
        Instance = new My_RunAnalysis(package, commandService);
    }

    //...
    private async void ExecuteAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await My_ViewModel.RunAnalysisAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
}

//...

class My_ViewModel
{
    async public static Task RunAnalysisAsync()
    {
        await My_Model.GetResultsListAsync();
    }
}

//...

class My_Model
    async public static Task GetResultsListAsync()
    {
        ResultsList = new My_ResultsList();

        var rawResultsList = await QueryServerAsync<RawResultsListResponse>("GET", My_Request.GetResults());

        //...
    }

    async public static Task<JsonResponse> QueryServerAsync<JsonResponse>(string method, 
        string request)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            switch (method)
            {
                case "GET":
                    response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(request);
                    break;
                case "POST":
                default:
                    StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(request, httpContent);
                    break;
            }

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //<<<<<<CASE #1
            {
                throw new My_Exception(
                response.ReasonPhrase,
                "Exception while querying server for " + request);
            }

            string serializedJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // CASE #2>>>>>
            var jsonResponse = serializer.Deserialize<JsonResponse>(serializedJson); 

            return jsonResponse;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new My_Exception(
                e.Message,
                "Exception while querying server for " + request);
        }
    }
```

The strange thing is that:

- When an error occurs in case #1 and I create a custom exception (my server responded but there was an internal error and I have a clean error code), the MessageBox in the catch of My_ViewModel::RunAnalysisAsync() will show correctly and immediately.
- When a native exception occurs in case #2 (my server responded with malformed json and I get an exception from serializer.Deserialize), the MessageBox in the catch of My_ViewModel::RunAnalysisAsync() will not show, the IDE will hang for around 15s before restarting (and still not show the MessageBox).

Any idea what's wrong?

Thanks!

> EDIT:
>
> Seeing that the template for my custom command initializes also with SwitchToMainThreadAsync, I have tried to do the same with the Execute method. I updated the code above but it still does not work: an exception thrown by serializer.Deserialize will still freeze the UI for 10 to 15s and the MessageBox will not show!
>
> Also note that the debugger can step immediately on "await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);" and go on next step to MessageBox. I would tend to suppose it means that the switch to the main thread is immediate but there is still something wrong...
>
> Any idea what's wrong? I really need to capture exceptions a reliable way...

Comment: Are you stepping through the catch where you create `My_Exception`, and also through the constructor for `My_Exception`?

Comment: MessageBox, like any dialog, requires an owner window.  One that it is guaranteed to be on top of and therefore always visible.  It is a bit too helpful by not forcing you to specify the owner, it then picks the active window on the current thread.  Which is where it falls down in this code, the call is made on a threadpool thread that doesn't own any windows.  Which makes the desktop window the owner.  Always good odds that it now appears *behind* the VS main window.

Comment: Hi Ed! Thanks for your reply. Yes, I confirm I can step through the catch, in both cases, and also in the My_Exception constructor, in both cases as well. I don't understand why it works on !response.IsSuccessStatusCode and not on serializer.Deserialize exception. Same portion of code usd with the same context. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Hans! Thanks for your reply. I understand your details about setting the dialog owner. But how come it works on !response.IsSuccessStatusCode and not on serializer.Deserialize exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any explanation to the MessageBox working on a case and not on the other one. I ended up going to some log solution using FileStream.WriteAsync. Hence everything keeps async and I don't have to use MessageBox anymore.

Answer (score 0):

use `await JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();` to switch to the main thread `JoinableTaskFactory` is a member of `AsyncPackage`.
If it still doesn't work try

```
public static void ShowMessageBox(string title, string text)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

            IVsUIShell uiShell = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsUIShell)) as IVsUIShell;
            Guid clsid = Guid.Empty;
            int result;
            Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(uiShell.ShowMessageBox(
                       0,
                       ref clsid,
                       title,
                       text,
                       string.Empty,
                       0,
                       OLEMSGBUTTON.OLEMSGBUTTON_OK,
                       OLEMSGDEFBUTTON.OLEMSGDEFBUTTON_FIRST,
                       OLEMSGICON.OLEMSGICON_INFO,
                       0,        // false
                       out result));
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. I tried both and there is no change: still failing with the exception on serializer.Deserialize. The UI hangs for 10 to 15s and the MessageBox will finally not show. Any other idea?

Comment: BTW, when using ThrowIfNotOnUIThread(), the compiler fails with the following message: error VSTHRD109: Avoid throwing when not on the main thread while in an async or Task-returning method. Switch to the thread required instead. I have got to remove this line... Already replaced by await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken).

Comment: Is there any relation with my problem: "Avoid throwing when not on the main thread while in an async or Task-returning method"? Then what is the best practice for handling exceptions in an async or Task-returning method? Because the methods I need *do* throw exceptions (serializer.Deserialize)...

Comment: About that I have found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#exceptions-in-async-methods, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx. I can confirm I __do__ get the exception in the catch block but the problem is still that I cannot reliably get the MessageBox displayed when getting an exception from serializer.Deserialize. Why does it work in case #1 and not case #2? Why would I be on the correct thread on case #1 and not case #2?